# On a symmetric equation over the integer lattice that involves the Euler's totient function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, exponentiation, totient-function

I would like to know hints or a proof, or counterexamples, for the conjecture that I've stated in the **Question** below. I'm interested in this in an attempt to continue the study of a question that I've posted on MathOverflow (the corresponding to the link for the cited thread of comments in the following paragraphs). The first I add the following claim, since our conjecture is the converse of this.

**Claim.** *If* $(x,y)$ *is a point of the integer lattice (I mean that both* $x$ *and* $y$ *are integers) with* $x\geq 1$ *an odd integer and* $x<y$, *then the equation* $$y^{y-x}(y-x)^y=2\cdot\frac{y-x}{\varphi(y-x)}\,\varphi(x^y y^x)\tag{1}$$
*holds for* $y=2\cdot x$*, where* $\varphi(m)$ *denotes the Euler's totient function.*

*Sketch of proof.* I'm inspired as starting point in the [thread of comments$^{*}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336501/what-work-can-be-done-to-study-the-solutions-of-varphi-leftx-sigmax-sigm#comment906886_336501) that I've posted in my question with identificator **336501** on MathOverflow and title *What work can be done to study the solutions of* $\varphi\left(x^{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)^x\right)=2^{x-1} x^{3x-1}\varphi(x)$*?* (asked Jul 19 '19). From here it is easy to check, for lattice points of the form $(x,y=2x)$ with $x$ an odd integer, that $$y^xx^y=y^x\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^y=2\cdot\frac{y-x}{\varphi(y-x)}\varphi(x^y y^x)$$
holds since $y=2x$, and from here we get $(1)$ because $y-x=x$.$\square$

> **Question.** I would like to know what work can be done to state the veracity of the following conjecture (converse of previous claim): *If* $(x,y)$ *is a point of the integer lattice, I mean that both* $x\geq 1$ *and* $y\geq 1$ *are integers, with* $x<y$*, and the equation* $$y^{y-x}(y-x)^y=2\cdot\frac{y-x}{\varphi(y-x)}\,\varphi(x^y y^x)$$
>   *holds,* **then** $x$ *is an odd integer and* $y$ *is twice times* $x$ *(in simple words that our points are of the form* $(x,y=2\cdot x)$ *for* $x\geq 1$ *and odd integer).* **Many thanks.**

If my question is feasible but tedious to get, feel free to add just a summary of hints, or a key idea. In other case add what work can be done about the veracity of the conjecture.

**Remarks and computational evidence.** The motivation to ask such thing (I'm agree that this seems an artificious characterization of those points of the integer lattice having the form $(\text{odd integers},\text{twice the odd numbers})$) is my study of the mentioned MO post. I can to test the conjecture that I've asked in Question for the segment of integers $1\leq x<y\leq 1000$ .

---

$^*$Thus, as aside remark (unrelated to our post), on assumption that there exists an odd perfect number $X$, the equation $$X^Y Y^X=(Y-X)^Y Y^{Y-X}=\frac{\sigma(X)}{\varphi(Y-X)}\,\varphi(X^Y Y^X)$$
holds for the lattice point $(X,Y=2X=\sigma(X))$, where $\sigma(m)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid m}d$ denotes the sum of positive  divisors function of an integer $m\geq 1$.

Comment: I hope that there aren't typos. Feel fre to add your feedback about the post. I'm going to try to post my ideas in next hours/days. Many thanks again to all users.

Comment: Many thanks for the attention of all users, help and for the upvoter.

Comment: If some user wants to explore the equation, for the integer lattice $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ under the condition $x<y$, $$y^{y-x}(y-x)^y=\lambda\cdot\frac{y-x}{\varphi(y-x)}\,\varphi(x^y y^x)$$ for (positive) rational numbers $\lambda\neq 2$, that he/she feels free to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conjecture is true.

*Proof* :

Firstly, let us prove that $2x-y\ge 0$.

Suppose that $2x-y\lt 0$.

If $y-x=2$, then $(x,y)=(1,3)$ for which the equation does not hold.

If $y-x\ge 3$, then since $\varphi(y-x)\ge 2$, we get
$$\begin{align}& y^{y-x}(y-x)^{y-1}\varphi(y-x)=2\varphi(x^y y^x)
\\\\&\implies 2y^{y-x}(y-x)^{y-1}\le y^{y-x}(y-x)^{y-1}\varphi(y-x)=2\varphi(x^y y^x)\lt 2x^yy^x
\\\\&\implies 2y^{y-x}(y-x)^{y-1}\lt 2x^yy^x
\\\\&\implies y^{y-2x}\lt x\bigg(\frac{x}{y-x}\bigg)^{y-1}
\\\\&\implies y\le y^{y-2x}\lt x\bigg(\frac{x}{y-x}\bigg)^{y-1}\lt x
\\\\&\implies y\lt x\end{align}$$
which is impossible. So, we have to have $2x-y\ge 0$.$\quad\square$

Secondly, let us prove that $2x-y\le 1$.

Suppose that $2x-y\gt 1$.

Using the fact that
$$\varphi(x^y y^x)=x^{y-1} y^{x-1}\varphi(xy)$$
we see that the equation can be written as
$$(y-x)^{y-1}\varphi(y-x)=2x^{y-1}y^{2x-y-1}\varphi(xy)\tag1$$

Since $\varphi(y-x)\lt y-x\lt x\le x^{y-1}$, we have $x^{y-1}\not\mid \varphi(y-x)$. So, we have to have $x^{y-1}\mid (y-x)^{y-1}$. It follows that there is a positive integer $k$ such that $y=kx$. It follows from $2x-kx\gt 1$ that $k=1$ for which LHS of $(1)$ equals $0$ while RHS of $(1)$ is positive. So, we have to have $2x-y\le 1$.$\quad\square$

Thirdly, let us prove that $2x-y\not=1$.

Suppose that $2x-y=1$. Then, we get
$$(x-1)^{2x-2}\varphi(x-1)=2x^{2x-2}\varphi(x(2x-1))$$
If $x=1$, this does not hold. If $x\gt 1$, we have to have
$$x^{2x-2}\mid \varphi(x-1)\implies x^{2x-2}\le \varphi(x-1)\lt x$$
which is impossible. So, we have to have $2x-y\not=1$.$\quad\square$

It follows that $y=2x$.

We can write $x=2^ab$ where $a$ is a non-negative integer and $b$ is a positive odd integer.

Suppose that $a\ge 1$. Then, we get
$$(2x)^{x}(x)^{2x-1}\varphi(x)=2\varphi(x^{2x} (2x)^x)\implies 2^{3ax+x-1}= 
 2^{3ax+x}$$
which is impossible. So, we have to have $a=0$.

Therefore, $x$ has to be odd with $y=2x$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Many thanks for share your result. I tried study some cases by substitution, but was failed because was tedious (also these last weeks I am a little tired). Your key ideas, honest work and knowledges are excellent. I'm going to study your answer.

Comment: @user759001 : Reading my answer carefully, I've just found an error in the "proof" that $y\ge 2x$. So, I've written some partial results.

Comment: Yes I believe that I've realized the use of an arithmetic function, that I believe isn't required in the equation.

Comment: @user759001: I've just got a proof that the conjecture is true.

Comment: I'm going to study your calculations, many thanks again and good day.